# CreateFile and its relative security

Tags: c++, windows, file, usb

I am working on some project which needs to write some configuration file to removable drive. I have all things set to write the configuration file with hidden attributes using windows API. Everything is working as expected.

But for my program to work that file need to be in removable drive. If some one by some means deletes that file my program will not at all work. Writing to removable drive is only option as user can take his removable drive to some other system and can use it there and configuration data will be different for each user.
So I want to make it somehow undeletable. How can I achieve the same?

These are few possibilities came to my mind.

1. through some custom warning dialogue to user when he tries to delete the file.
2. ask for pin/password which i will use while creating file and then delete the file.
3. provide a saperate utility for removal of configuration and deny file deletion from all other ways.

So what will be the best approach for this or any other approach. Please suggest me in proper direction and way to implement it.

Comment: If you write stuff on a removable drive you have already lost; nothing stops the user to put in on a machine with another OS and bypass any kind of botched security you tried to implement.

Comment: ya its ok. let the user put it on some other machine and do changes.we have few things to take care of such cases.for now only my concern is to prevent it from deletion or deletion with permission.

Comment: I wouldn't overthink this; just mark it with the "system" attribute and the OS will warn the user that deleting the file is a bad idea. If he does anyway, bummer. Anything else is going to be a kludge that won't work in 90% cases.

Comment: @Nimish: you're missing the point... "let the user... do changes" *includes* "deletion"... you can't prevent that, you can only give the tiniest obfuscation by hiding the file in some way that a limited set of operating systems might honour (e.g. if it's a FAT32 format with the hidden atrribute, perhaps with a leading full-stop if reading from UNIX/Linux, maybe by giving it a weird name they're unlikely to think of deleting).  A more sophisticated approach is to format the device so some of the memory's not allocated to the filesystem and store your content in the "unused" area.

Comment: ...Or write it in some not-yet-used area and pray the device doesn't use it anytime soon.  No good solution.

Comment: @TonyD I mean if user make any changes in config file i have logic to check for it. and writing into unused content sounds interesting but my limitation is i dont have permission to format device

Comment: Ok, sounds good, so your only issue is preventing deletion - as everyone's been telling you you can not prevent it.  Your ideas of warning dialogues or asking for pin/password seems to assume you'll have a program running on the "other PC" they put the removable drive into, and no other program will be able to access it.  If that's true then you should explain it in your question, and tell us what's to prevent them finding an entirely different machine without your software on it, and deleting the file from there?

Comment: @TonyD yehh i didn't give thought on it. thanks for making me notice it. so what i feel is there is no such way to prevent it from deletion but to mark it as SYSTEM attib as suggested by matteo atleast OS will warn for it.

Comment: Some USB drives are NTFS formatted, in which case you can assign file permissions.  The user can override them, but it should prevent accidental deletion.